# How to run multiple Python scripts and an executable files using Docker?

Tags: python, linux, bash, docker, docker-compose

I want to create a container that is contained with two Python packages as well as a package consist of an executable file.

---

#### Here's my main package (dockerized_package) tree:

```
dockerized_project
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
├── exec_project
│   ├── config
│   │   └── config.json
│   ├── config.json
│   ├── gowebapp
├── pythonic_project1
│   ├── __main__.py
│   ├── requirements.txt
│   ├── start.sh
│   └── utility
│       └── utility.py
└── pythonic_project2
    ├── collect
    │   ├── collector.py
    ├── __main__.py
    ├── requirements.txt
    └── start.sh
```

---

#### Dockerfile content:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
        
RUN apt update
RUN apt-get install -y python3.6 python3-pip python3-dev build-essential gcc \
    libsnmp-dev snmp-mibs-downloader

RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip

RUN mkdir /app
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app/snmp_collector
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
WORKDIR /app/proto_conversion
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

WORKDIR /app/pythonic_project1
CMD python3 __main__.py

WORKDIR /app/pythonic_project2
CMD python3 __main__.py

WORKDIR /app/exec_project
CMD ["./gowebapp"]
```

---

#### docker-compose content:

```
version: '3'

services:
  proto_conversion:
      build: .
      image: pc:2.0.0
      container_name: proto_conversion
#      command: 
#        - "bash  snmp_collector/start.sh"
#        - "bash  proto_conversion/start.sh"
      restart: unless-stopped
      ports:
        - 8008:8008
      tty: true
```

---

## Problem:

When I run this project with `docker-compose up --build`, only the last `CMD` command runs. Hence, I think the previous `CMD` commands are killed in `Dockerfile` because when I remove the last two `CMD`, the first `CMD` works well.

Is there any approach to run multiple Python scripts and an executable file in the background?

I've also tried with the bash files without any success either.

Comment: Are you trying to start your application during build time?

Comment: I don't know you mean. In my Dockerfile the running project procedure is clarified. My problem is running multiple python script in the Docker file with `CMD`. when next `CMD` ran the previous `CMD` killed, I tried also with `nohub`.

Comment: FWIW you can pass a list of packages as arguments to `apt install`. Just `apt install -y package1 package2 package3` ...

Comment: I think you should have a look at the [interaction of `CMD` and `ENTRYPOINT`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#understand-how-cmd-and-entrypoint-interact). You can only have one `CMD` in one Dockerfile (see [`CMD` documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd)) but you can combine `ENTRYPOINT` and `CMD` as shown in the first link.

Comment: My understanding is that you should still prefer `apt-get` over `apt` for noninteractive use.

Comment: @tripleee Thanks for the suggestion. Even in `18.04` `apt-get` should be preferred?

Comment: Question is same what exactly I Want to know. Question is nicely asked here..Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd), there can be only one CMD in the docker file and if there is more, the last one overrides the others and takes effect. 
A key point of using docker might be to isolate your programs, so at first glance, you might want to move them to separate containers and talk to each other using a shared volume or a docker network, but if you really need them to run in the same container, including them in a bash script and replacing the last CMD with CMD `run.sh` will run them alongside each other:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec python3 /path/to/script1.py &
exec python3 /path/to/script2.py
```

Add `COPY run.sh` to the Dockerfile and use `RUN chmod a+x run.sh` to make it executable. CMD should be `CMD ["./run.sh"]`

Comment: The first `exec` is pointless; the shell already takes care of running the background process separately.

Comment: And how about `gowebapp` executable file?

Comment: Maybe adding `&` at the end of the second python line and adding `./gowebapp` in the third line?

Answer (score 5):

try it via entrypoint.sh

```
ENTRYPOINT ["/docker_entrypoint.sh"]
```

`docker_entrypoint.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

exec python3 not__main__.py &
exec python3 __main__.py
```

symbol `&` says that you run service as daemon in background

Comment: each `__main__.py` placed in different folder.

Comment: use cd or python3 ../../folder/script.py

Comment: The `exec` statements seem useless here.  The `set -e` offers no benefits for background jobs. Probably take it out along with both `exec` statements, leaving just two `python3` commands with different arguments.

Comment: I would use `set -m`. See [set docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/The-Set-Builtin.html)

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is to launch these as three separate containers.  That's doubly true since you're taking three separate applications, bundling them into a single container, and then trying to launch three separate things from them.

Create a separate Dockerfile in each of your project subdirectories.  These can be simpler, especially for the one that just contains a compiled binary

```sh
# execproject/Dockerfile
FROM ubuntu:18.04
WORKDIR /app
COPY . ./
CMD ["./gowebapp"]
```

Then in your `docker-compose.yml` file have three separate stanzas to launch the containers

```
version: '3'
services:
  pythonic_project1:
    build: ./pythonic_project1
    ports:
      - 8008:8008
    env:
      PY2_URL: 'http://pythonic_project2:8009'
      GO_URL: 'http://execproject:8010'
  pythonic_project2:
    build: ./pythonic_project2
  execproject:
    build: ./execproject
```

If you really can't rearrange your Dockerfiles, you can at least launch three containers from the same image in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
services:
  pythonic_project1:
    build: .
    workdir: /app/pythonic_project1
    command: ./__main__.py
  pythonic_project2:
    build: .
    workdir: /app/pythonic_project1
    command: ./__main__.py
```

There's several good reasons to structure your project with multiple containers and images:

- If you roll your own shell script and use background processes (as other answers have), it just won't notice if one of the processes dies; here you can use Docker's restart mechanism to restart individual containers.
- If you have an update to one of the programs, you can update and restart only that single container and leave the rest intact.
- If you ever use a more complex container orchestrator (Docker Swarm, Nomad, Kubernetes) the different components can run on different hosts and require a smaller block of CPU/memory resource on a single node.
- If you ever use a more complex container orchestrator, you can individually scale up components that are using more CPU.