# Python web App Multiprocessing/Multithreading connexion[swagger-ui]

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing, swagger, connexion

I have a Python Web App defined using `connexion[swagger-ui]`, on my `my_app.py` file:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # run our standalone gevent server
    application.run(server='gevent', port=8080)
```

Now, I have another python file, `test.py` that is always calling an API in order to get some data:

```
def f():
    while True:
        ... # Call API and handles data
```

Both on the same project. Now, I was trying some approaches as [multiprocessing package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html), to have those tasks running without blocking each other, but without success. Is there any suggestion or best approach to implement this?

Comment: Linux and Windows allow multitasking, i.e. multiple processes can run concurrently. Just run the two as separate processes, e.g. from the shell. Note: in case it's a unit test, there is normally no need for two separate processes: all you need is a test client that short-circuits the HTTP requests to the handlers of the framework (I have never used the one you mention l)

Comment: If `connexion` is a Flask extension, you can use Flask's [test client](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.15.x/test/#werkzeug.test.Client)

Comment: Both process are running on a docker container.

Comment: @Pynchia Thanks. I could start both process on the same container by following some information provided in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920742/how-to-run-multiple-python-scripts-and-an-executable-files-using-docker). It's is more related to Docker than Multi-threading. Now I'm just starting both processes on the same container. I know that the best approach would be to have two separated containers, but for what I pretend now this is enough.