# Shell file not found inside docker compose/dockerfile containers

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I have multiple Python scripts from which I want to run a docker container. From a related question [How to run multiple Python scripts and an executable files using Docker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53920742/how-to-run-multiple-python-scripts-and-an-executable-files-using-docker) , I found that the best way to do that is to have `run.sh` a shell file as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 producer.py &
python3 consumer.py &
python3 test_conn.py
```

and then call this file from a Dockerfile as:

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

CMD ["./run.sh"]
```

However, in the container logs the following error is prompting `exec ./run.sh: no such file or directory`, which makes no sense to me since I copied everything on the current directory, run.sh included, to /usr/src/app on my container via `COPY . /usr/src/app`

Please, clone my repo and on the root directory call docker-compose up -d and check myapp container logs to help me.

https://github.com/Quilograma/IES_Project

Thank you!

Can't run multiple python scripts in a single container.

Comment: Your bash script has no `&` at the end of each line, so it will run each program one at a time. This is probably not what you intended.

Comment: @NickODell You're right, thanks for pointing it out! Not the cause though.

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly specify what shell interpreter be used for running your script.

Changing the last line to `CMD ["bash", "-c", "./run.sh"]` might solve your issue.

Comment: thank you. Not the cause though.

Comment: What was the cause?

Comment: Had to add RUN sed -i -e 's/\r$//' run.sh on the dockerfile as stated in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219092/bash-script-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

You need to chmod run.sh to be excecuteable:

```
FROM python:3.9

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app

WORKDIR /usr/src/app

COPY requirements.txt /usr/src/app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY . /usr/src/app

RUN chmod +x run.sh

CMD ["./run.sh"]
```

Comment: Didn't work @zsolt

Comment: @MartimSousa okay, I see that your line endings were messed up, this is why questions should always include the OS (at least win/linux/mac) and all the relevant software versions. This Dockerfile I gave is still a better approach to deal with file execution permissions, to set it explicitly in image build time through Dockerfile instead of relying on that the file is add-ed, commited to the git repo with `--chmod=+x` flag or to rely on the host filesystem of the builder machine.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to run three separate long-running processes, do not try to orchestrate them from a shell script.  Instead, launch three separate containers.  If you're running this via Compose, this is straightforward: have three containers all running the same image, but override the `command:` to run different main processes.

```yaml
version: '3.8'
services:
  producer:
    build: .
    command: ./producer.py
  consumer:
    build: .
    command: ./consumer.py
  test_conn:
    build: .
    command: ./test_conn.py
```

Make sure the scripts are executable (run `chmod +x producer.py` on your host system, and commit that to source control) and begin with a "shebang" line `#!/usr/bin/env python3` as the very first line.

Comment: yeah that's another way of calling the python scripts, but the error persists.

Didn't really understand what you meant by chmod +x producer.py and #!/usr/bin/env python3. I'm a begginer....

Answer (score -2):

For those encountering the same problem adding `RUN sed -i -e 's/\r$//' run.sh` on the Dokcerfile before `CMD ["bash", "-c", "./run.sh"]` is what worked for me. See [Bash script – "/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14219092/bash-script-bin-bashm-bad-interpreter-no-such-file-or-directory) for further details.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).