# Docker - exec ./run.sh: no such file or directory

Tags: windows, docker

I'm currently following the [FastAPI](https://christophergs.com/tutorials/ultimate-fastapi-tutorial-pt-13-docker-deploy/) tutorial by ChristopherGS and I'm unfortunately running into an issue on the step to run docker compose.
It's supposed to be spinning up two Docker containers, 'part-13-docker-deployment-db-1' (which is up and running properly) and 'part-13-docker-deployment-web-1', which is starting but exits with the following error shown in the Docker logs: `exec ./run.sh: no such file or directory`

If you want to try this yourself, the repo is publicly hosted and I believe the issue is stemming from this line here: https://github.com/ChristopherGS/ultimate-fastapi-tutorial/blob/main/part-13-docker-deployment/backend/Dockerfile#L47

I'm on a Windows machine, which I've seen messages and the like indicating that mounting issues are common with Docker, however I'm unable to determine if that's the cause here or not. Unfortunately only that one line is visible in the logs in Docker Desktop and no error messages - or even warnings - appear in the terminal where I'm running it.

The only other thread I could find that seemed to be related was [Shell file not found inside docker compose/dockerfile containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74493795/shell-file-not-found-inside-docker-compose-dockerfile-containers) however none of the solutions proposed worked for me. I've attempted specifying the interpreter and cleaning the file name with the given sed command, but neither of those work and as you can see in the repo link the file is already being modded to be executable.

From what I can tell, it's in the correct working directory, so I don't see why the file would not be found nor would it be executable.

EDIT: I've confirmed that it *is* in the correct directory by the time it reaches the `CMD ["./run.sh"]` line, as I included a `RUN pwd && ls -l` right before that command should run and the output was as follows:

```
#14 [10/10] RUN pwd && ls -l
#14 0.445 /app
#14 0.447 total 112
#14 0.447 drwxr-xr-x  3 root root  4096 Nov 29 14:04 alembic
#14 0.447 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root  1663 Nov 29 14:04 alembic.ini
#14 0.447 drwxr-xr-x 11 root root  4096 Nov 29 14:04 app
#14 0.447 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root 83711 Nov 29 14:04 poetry.lock
#14 0.447 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   345 Nov 29 14:04 prestart.py
#14 0.447 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   180 Nov 29 14:04 prestart.sh
#14 0.447 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   641 Nov 29 14:04 pyproject.toml
#14 0.447 -rwxr-xr-x  1 root root   708 Nov 29 14:04 run.sh
#14 DONE 0.5s

#15 exporting to image
#15 exporting layers
#15 exporting layers 0.8s done
#15 writing image sha256:a14684e21dd168ec37696fc64f1d57dbd05a146ff8694cf2fe6fc4a134014500 done
#15 DONE 0.8s
```

Comment: In GitHub, it shows the file is 686 bytes. The directory listing show that it is 708 bytes. Can you show the commands you are running and their output to prove that this is not an issue with windows linefeeds?

Comment: If you have details of how this is different from this or similar duplicates, feel free to edit the question with how it's different and I can reopen it.

Comment: @BMitch To get that output I just did a `docker build --progress=plain --no-cache .`
Whereas the command I'm running normally trying to get all this to start up is `docker-compose -f docker-compose.local.yml up -d`. When doing a direct comparison, the files I have no differences so it's possible it's the linefeeds you were mentioning

Comment: Looks like this was the fix it needed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51508150/standard-init-linux-go190-exec-user-process-caused-no-such-file-or-directory